# How do I submit a SearchView programmatically?

Tags: android, submit, searchview

I'm trying to submit a `SearchView` that I have in my `Toolbar` from a click of a `Button` that I created in my layout.

This is the relevant code in my search activity:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    ....
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        makeQuery(query);
        return true;
    }
});

searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // searchView submit??
    }
});
```

Is there any method like `searchView.onSubmit()` `searchView.onQuerySubmit();`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this

```
searchView.setQuery(searchView.getQuery(), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, try to use `SearchView#setQuery(CharSequence query, boolean submit)`. This will submit your request if `true`. If `false` only query data will be changed.

Hope, it helps